# How to prevent blur from using colors outside of the texture?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es-2.0, shader

I'm trying to create a shader that blurs, and I've done that. However, theres one problem. Around the texture there is a black background, and when the shader runs it is grabbing color from that background and it ends up darkening my entire image (but it still blurs the image just fine, its just as if it is also lowering the brightness). Just to be sure thats what I thought was going on, I set the background white, and sure enough it made my image duller. I don't really know how to prevent this, I suppose its grabbing them outside because the blur size is reaching outside the texture boundary, is there any way to prevent texture look ups from occuring outside of the texture I'm dealing with?

frag:

```
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D CC_Texture0;  
uniform float u_time;

const lowp int SAMPLES = 9;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;        
varying highp vec2 transCord[SAMPLES];

void main()
{
      vec4 sum = vec4(0.0);

    sum += texture2D(CC_Texture0, transCord[0]) * 0.05;
    sum += texture2D(CC_Texture0, transCord[1]) * 0.09;
    sum += texture2D(CC_Texture0, transCord[2]) * 0.12;
    sum += texture2D(CC_Texture0, transCord[3]) * 0.15;
    sum += texture2D(CC_Texture0, transCord[4]) * 0.16;
    sum += texture2D(CC_Texture0, transCord[5]) * 0.15;
    sum += texture2D(CC_Texture0, transCord[6]) * 0.12;
    sum += texture2D(CC_Texture0, transCord[7]) * 0.09;
    sum += texture2D(CC_Texture0, transCord[8]) * 0.05;

      gl_FragColor = sum;
}
```

Vertex shader

```
precision mediump float;

attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;

const lowp int SAMPLES = 9;

uniform highp float texelWidthOffset;
uniform highp float texelHeightOffset;
uniform highp float blurSize;
uniform float u_time;

varying vec2 v_texCoord;        
varying highp vec2 transCord[SAMPLES];

void main()
{
      gl_Position = CC_MVPMatrix * a_position;
    v_texCoord = a_texCoord;    
    highp vec2 offset = vec2(texelWidthOffset, texelHeightOffset) * (u_time * blurSize);

    transCord[0] = a_texCoord - offset * 4.0;
    transCord[1] = a_texCoord - offset * 3.0;
    transCord[2] = a_texCoord - offset * 2.0;
    transCord[3] = a_texCoord - offset * 1.0;
    transCord[4] = a_texCoord;
    transCord[5] = a_texCoord + offset * 1.0;
    transCord[6] = a_texCoord + offset * 2.0;
    transCord[7] = a_texCoord + offset * 3.0;
    transCord[8] = a_texCoord + offset * 4.0;
}
```

UPDATE: It appears this is only an issue when rendering on to CCRenderTexture. I'm not sure why though.

Answer (score 0):

Set the wrap modes of the texture, in both S and T, to GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE -- this will mean that out-of-range UV coordinate vales return more-sensible results